# cout weird output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When I try using cout, it outputs a random number rather then the sentence I want. There is not compiler error, the program runs fine.

Here is my code:

```
//question.h
#ifndef _QUESTION_H_
#define _QUESTION_H_

using namespace std;
int first()
{
    cout<<"question \n";
    return 0;
}

#endif

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "question.h"

using namespace std;

void main(){
    cout<<""<<first<<""<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

I'm fairly new to writing my own header files, so I'm not sure if I did something wrong with that or if there's a problem with visual studio.

Comment: first() returns an int but does some stream injecting... I don't even know what would happen if it was doing what you think you intend it to do.

Comment: @GradyPlayer, Indeed. Here's an example where the output from the function is first: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3RyOu1%243

Comment: Excellent example @chris, I was wondering if that buffer would get flushed first... Or if it called first into a register / tmp location before the other stream operation.

Comment: This may look weird but is well-defined: the output is the first empty string, the string `"question \n"`, the character `'0'`, the second empty string, and a newline, in that order.  This is because every invocation of `operator<<` provides a sequence point on either side.  (If this didn't work it wouldn't be possible to chain `cout << a << b << c << ...` at all.)

Comment: @Zack, Shouldn't it be the same thing as `std::cout << i << ' ' << ++i;`? That could print `i i+1` or `i+1 i`. This could do the same thing and print `"" "question \n"` or `"question \n" ""`. In the example I linked to, it prints `"question \n" ""1 0 ""2`, where `""1` and `""2` are the first and second empty strings respectively.

Comment: @chris I didn't think so, but seeing your demo now I'm not sure.  I would have thought that the implicit sequence points on either side of each `operator<<` forced strict left-to-right evaluation, including not calling the function until after everything to the left of it had been printed.

Comment: @Zack, This might make for a good question to clear things up if it isn't already on here. It must be distinctive from the constantly recurring "Why do I get different results when printing `std::cout << i << i++;`?" questions, though. Feel free to ask it if you want to.

Comment: @chris Hang on, is `cout << i << i++` unspecified behavior?  If so, I don't know what I'm talking about.  (I don't use iostreams if I can possibly avoid it, so there's an excellent chance I indeed don't know how this works.)

Comment: @Zack, If we imagine it as `operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, ""), first()), "");`, I think there would be a sequence point (at least in pre-C++11 terms) at each function call. Before that happens, the arguments must all be evaluated. That means that `""`, `first()`, and `""` would all have to be evaluated in an unspecified order (which shouldn't actually matter here with this logic) before any output is produced. After each output should be a sequence point to keep things in order. I think the output from `first()` must always be the first thing then and the others in order.

Comment: Or maybe I'm doing it wrong and it could be the case that the most inner `""` could be evaluated with the paired `std::cout` and output before `first()` is evaluated, all of which could happen before or after the outer `""` is evaluated, but the outer would not be printed yet because the inner calls have not been evaluated. I think that might be how it is, in which case it would either be output first or after the first empty string.

Comment: @Zack, I should have done this before, but I ran it on the available C++ compilers on LWS. All GCCs put the `first()` output first, and Intel and Clang put it after the first empty string ("abc" in the example). That inconclusively points to my second wall of text. As soon as I can be sure about what could happen, I'll update my answer with the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 5):

You're printing the address of the function. You need to call it:

```
cout<<""<<first()<<""<<endl;
               ^^
```

As mentioned in the comments, this doesn't have to output what you expect, either. The order in which arguments to functions (and that is just a bunch of function calls) is unspecified, so your function output could be in any position the compiler chooses. To fix this, put separate statements:

```
cout<<"";
cout<<first(); //evaluated, so output inside first() printed before return value
cout<<""<<endl;
```

It might not matter with the empty strings, but it will when you replace those with something visible.

Also, don't use `void main`. Use `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)` ([see here](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main)). Don't use `using namespace std;`, especially in headers, as `std` has a lot of crap in it that is pulled in with that statement, leading to easy and confusing conflicts ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)). Finally, choose a name that does not conflict with [identifiers reserved for the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) as your include guard.

Comment: There isn't an evaluation order issue in the OP's code.  If corrected to call `first` instead of just taking its address, it can be relied upon to print `@question \n0#$` where `@` is the empty string to the left of `first`, `#` is the empty string to its right, and `$` is `endl`.  But I think it was *meant* to print just `@question \n#$` -- the OP appears to have thought that this was how you write a "manipulator"-like iostream item.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address of the function `first` rather than calling it.  But changing the function call won't fix your problem all by itself, because `first` writes to `cout` internally and then returns a number, which will be printed, which doesn't appear to be what you want.

If you want `first` to act like an `<iomanip>` thingie you have to jump through a few more hoops -- read that header to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cout<<""<<first()<<""<<endl;`  you need to actually call the function, not print its address